# Opposite of "most recently"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, antonyms

What is a good way to formulate the opposite of "most recently"? For example,

> Display the five most recently updated streams.
>
> The two most recently hired coders are doing a great job.

How do I better formulate these?

> Display the five streams where the greatest amount of time has passed
>   since they were last updated.
>
> The two coders where the greatest amount of time has passed since they
>   were hired are doing a great job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The opposite of *most* is *least*, so you could say:

> Display the five least recently updated streams
>
> The two least recently hired coders are doing a great job.

Comment: That makes sense to me

Answer (score 4):

For the second case, you could say ***most senior***.  As in, "The five *most senior* coders are doing a great job."

Answer (score 2):

Display the five *stalest* streams.

Comment: To my knowledge, when "stale" is used to describe sth other than food, it means "lacking originality" or "having lost effectiveness". This answer is misleading.

Comment: @Irene It would be understood correctly for streams in a software context because _stale_ is the opposite of _fresh_ and _fresh_ means recently _refreshed_ or _updated_.  Using _stale_ to refer to coders makes it sound like they smell bad (which is possible, but probably not what the OP was looking for).

Answer (score 0):

For the "streams" example, I agree with @simchona. The subject is technical and I think one gets away with "least recently" even though it sounds "clunky" to the ear.

For the "coders" example, I suggest a more direct statement:

> The two coders hired first are doing a great job.

or

> The two coders we hired first are doing a great job.